# How do I reach the gold key on floor 8 (Archives)?

Tags: hammerwatch

In Hammerwatch, you have to collect different coloured keys in order to open different coloured doors to progress. The screencap below shows a part of floor eight, where a gold key is currently inaccessible to me. **How do I retrieve it**, in order to open the gold door nearby?

[image: Key and door]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to come at it from below after hitting a switch that remove part of the wall.

(get the silver key and follow the sequence of passages opened by the floor switch behind 
the silver door).

The following video shows this being done:

Comment: Does that need to be done from floor 9 or something? I can't find a way to access that area from floor 8.

Comment: @shanodin no. There should be a silver key door, with a floor switch in it. Activating it should open a passage south-east of you, which will lead you to where you need to go. This sequence is started at about 3:10 in the video.